# How do I bring an Extjs 4 draw component sprite to the top on mouse over?

Tags: extjs

If I add paths to a drawComponent and they overlap, the paths are stacked in the order they're added.  I can add an event listener to each sprite so that it changes color and stroke width when I mouse over, but how do I bring the paths that are overlapped to the front?

This is the set of listeners to change color:

```
listeners: {
    mouseover: function(line) {
        line.setAttributes({ stroke: "red", "stroke-width": 8}, true );
    },
    mouseout: function(line) {
        line.setAttributes({ stroke: "black", "stroke-width": 4 }, true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the following works, but I have to believe there's a better way.  You can move something to the front by removing it and adding it back. However, removing it removes the mouse* listeners, so I had to move the listeners up a notch, like this (this is inside a component that has a drawComponent property (and is "me" by this point).

```
var pathout = function(line,target,opts) {
    line.setAttributes({ stroke: "blue", "stroke-width": 2 }, true );
    line.on('mouseover',pathover, this,opts);
};
var pathover = function(line,target,opts) {
    me.drawComponent.surface.remove(line,true);
    me.drawComponent.surface.add( line ).show(true);
    line.setAttributes({ stroke: "red", "stroke-width": 4}, true );
    line.on('mouseout',pathout,this,opts);

};
this.paths[pathName] = { 
    type: "path", 
    path: "M" + path.join(" L"), 
    stroke: next_color, 
    "stroke-width": 2,
    listeners: {
        mouseover: pathover,
        mouseout: pathout,
        scope: this
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This is also possible instead of re-adding.

```
                var marker = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite',{
                    type: 'circle',
                    fill: 'red',
                    surface : me.surface,
                    radius: 2,
                    x : sprite.x,
                    y : sprite.y
                });

                marker.show(true);
```